# generalization of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be differentiable at $x=x_0$ and suppose that $f(t)$ is continuous in the interval between $a(x_0)$ and $b(x_0)$. Is it true that
$$
F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt
$$
is differentiable at $x=x_0$ and
$$
F'(x_0)=f(b(x_0))b'(x_0)-f(a(x_0))a'(x_0)\  ? 
$$
Do we need additional assumptions for the truths of the claim? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is true. The proof is a consequence of the chain rule. Let $G$ be any  antiderivative of $f$. Then $$F(x) = G(b(x))- G(a(x))$$. Now derive with respect to $x$ and you are done.

Comment: I believe, at one point in time, at least, this was called The Rolling Carpet Theorem.